# LINQ statements in generic function

Tags: vb.net, linq, generics

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. The data access in through a repository that has a simple caching functionality. It contains several functions like the follwing two:

```
Public Function SelectAllCurrencies() As List(Of store_Currency) 
    Dim AllCurrencies As List(Of store_Currency)
    If UseCaching Then
        AllCurrencies = HttpContext.Current.Cache("AllCurrencies")
        If AllCurrencies Is Nothing Then
            AllCurrencies = (From Currencies In db.Currencies Order By Currencies.Title Ascending).ToList
            Cache.AddToCache("AllCurrencies", AllCurrencies)
        End If
    Else
        AllCurrencies = (From Currencies In db.Currencies Order By Currencies.Title Ascending).ToList
    End If
    Return AllCurrencies
End Function

Public Function SelectAllCountries() As List(Of store_Country) 
    Dim AllCountries As List(Of store_Country)
    If UseCaching Then
        AllCountries = HttpContext.Current.Cache("AllCountries")
        If AllCountries Is Nothing Then
            AllCountries = (From Countries In db.Countries Order By Countries.Title Ascending).ToList
            Cache.AddToCache("AllCountries", AllCountries)
        End If
    Else
        AllCountries = (From Countries In db.Countries Order By Countries.Title Ascending).ToList
    End If
    Return AllCountries
End Function
```

As you can see, they use the same workflow, over and over again. I want to remove this redundancy. I think that generics should provide a solution, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to deal with the LINQ statements in a generic `SelectAllEntities(Of T)` function. Is there a way to 'generalize' the queries, maybe with dynamic LINQ?

Comment: Is it no just a parameter of type `IEnumerable(Of T)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VB is a little rusty but I think you want to write your function like this.

```
Public SelectAll(Of T, TOrder)(
        IEnumerable(Of T) source,
        Func(Of T, TOrder) keySelector,
        cacheKey As String = Nothing) As IList(Of T)

    Dim all As List(Of T)
    If me.UseCaching Then
        all = HttpContext.Current.Cache(cacheKey)
        If all Is Nothing Then
            all = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList()
            Cache.AddToCache(cacheKey, all)
        End If
    Else
        all = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList()
    End If
    Return all
End Function
```

Which you could use like this

```
Dim allCountries = SelectAll(db.Countries, Function(c) c.Title, "AllCountries")
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! Together with the answer of @ethicallogics I should be able to figure out the way that is the best match for our code base. I'll have to see how my solution turns out, in order to know which answer to accept, though ;-) Side note: VB syntax makes my eyes hurt...

Answer (score 2):

```
        public List<T> GenericMethod<T>(string str)
    {
        List<T> list;
        list=HttpContext.Current.Cache(str);
        if(list==null)
        {
            using(var db=new ObjectContext())
            {
                 list=db.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToList();
            }
         }
        return list;
    }
    public void GetCountries()
    {
        var countries = GenericMethod<AllCountries>("AllCountries").OrderBy(o => o.Title).ToList();
    }

    public void GetCurrencies()
    {
        var currencies = GenericMethod<AllCurrencies>("AllCurrencies").OrderBy(o => o.Title).ToList();
    }
```

and I expect db is object of ObjectContext . I hope this will help.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks a lot! Not sure if this is the final answer, but it definitely gives me a starting point!